# how to handle multi string in YAML with helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Following is yaml content. I need to change the host values using --set in helm upgrade command.

```
route:
  hosts:
    - host: abc.xyz1.com
    - host: abc.xyz.com
```

I tried below way .

```
 --set 'route.hosts={abc.xyz2.com,abc.xyz1.com}'
```

but still value is not getting set . Please suggest , what should be the proper argument in --set option

Here is the error :

```
 at <.host>: can't evaluate field host in type interface {}
```

Comment: please suggest , not getting where is the issue

Comment: It can be hard to provide complex values like this only via command-line options, and `helm install --set` doesn't have a particularly regular syntax.  Can you write this fragment into an additional YAML (or JSON) file, and pass that file name using the `helm install -f` option instead?